# Javascript declaring a function in an Object

Tags: javascript

I am looking at some old code and some of the functions are defined as option 1 and others as option 2.

Is there a difference between these function declarations:

Option 1

```
obj.util.test = function util$test(x){  
... 
}
```

Option 2

```
obj.util.test = function (x){
...
}
```

Comment: If you got many different `test` functions, identifying the `util$test` function among them might help in debugging. Apart from that, there's hardly any difference.

Answer (score 0):

In this case they are both identical.

- In Options 1 property `test` is created using a named function.
- In Options 2 property `test` is created using a anonymous function.

Named functions  are useful because can be seen in stack traces and call stacks.